Koine Greek: What is the meaning of εργαζεϲθε?
Could you please describe the meaning of the word εργαζεϲθε.
The context is:
και γαρ οτε ημεν προϲ υμαϲ παρηγγελλομεν υμιν οτι ει τιϲ ου θελει εργαζεϲθε μηδε εϲθιετω
The reason for asking here is not to get the translation, but to get context. Many words may be translated, but they can also have a different historical or contextual meaning.

The reason for asking here is not to get the translation, but to get context.
Many words may be translated, but they can also have a different historical or contextual meaning.

Any particular reason you're using a non-standard text (lunate sigmas, no accents, diphthongs changed)? ἐργάζεσθαι is the more usual form.

It is the oldest New Testament text I've found.
The question was asked in order to understand if the meaning of the word is what we commonly understand as "to work".
I am unable to read or understand any of the text.

This question might be more relevant to the Bible studies than the Greek language. The sentence is 2 Thessalonians 3:10 and standardly given as

καὶ γὰρ ὅτε ἦμεν πρὸς ὑμᾶς, τοῦτο παρηγγέλλομεν ὑμῖν, ὅτι εἴ τις οὐ
θέλει ἐργάζεσθαι μηδὲ ἐσθιέτω.

which the King James Bible translates as

For even when we were with you, this we commanded you, that if any
would not work, neither should he eat.

It seems nothing out of ordinary senses of ἐργάζεσθαι (i.e., to work, trade,  acquire by labour) hangs over here.
To follow up the occurrences of ἐργάζομαι and related comments, one may wish to go to https://biblehub.com/greek/strongs_2038.htm.
